# strugling with awk script need help to done this just need your suggestion or logic

Tags: awk

I have a sql file to filter the data

```
-- Edit this file by adding your SQL below each question.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------
-- The following queries are based on the 1994 census data.
-------------------------------------------------------------

.read 1994
-census-summary-1.sql

-- 4. what is the average age of people from China?
select avg(age)
from census
where native_country ='China';

-- 5. what is the average age of people from Taiwan?
select avg(age)
from census
where native_country ='Taiwan';

-- 6. which native countries have "land" in their name?
select distinct(native_country)
from census
where native_country like '%land%';

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The following queries are based on the courses-ddl.sql and courses-small.sql data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

drop table census;
.read courses-ddl.sql
.read courses-small-1.sql

-- 11. what are the names of all students who have taken some course? Don't show duplicates.
select distinct(name)
from student
where tot_cred > 0;

-- 12. what are the names of departments that offer 4-credit courses? Don't list duplicates.
select distinct(dept_name)
from course
where credits=4;

-- 13. What are the names and IDs of all students who have received an A in a computer science class?
select distinct(name), id
from student natural join takes natural join course  
where dept_name="Comp. Sci." and grade="A";
```

if I run

./script.awk -v ID=6 file.sql

Note that the problem id is passed to the awk script as variable ID on the command line, like this:
-v ID=6

How Can I get the result like
Result :

`select distinct(native_country) from census where native_country like '%land%';`

Comment: Your headline says "Struggling with awk script ...", but you  haven't included your best attempt to solve the problem. Please edit your question to include what you "feel" is your best attempt to solve this and people will be able to show you why you are struggling and how to overcome that struggle! Good luck.

Comment: So pretty much you appear to be asking "Given a variable no (6), read from `--6` until empty line (first line is a comment), and make it all 1 line as final output.  Read lines in awk until you see desired line, then set a flag. And append read lines into another variable until you meet an empty line.   Go over problem on paper, and simplify. Then it's much simpler to solve.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples and in GNU `awk`, please try following GNU `awk` code using its `match` function. Where `id` is an `awk` variable has value which you want to make sure should be checked in lines of your Input_file. Also I have used `exit` to get/print the very first match and get out of program to save some time/cycle, in case you have more than one matches then simply remove it from following code.

```
awk -v RS= -v id="6" '
match($0,/(\n|^)-- ([0-9]+)\.[^\n]*\n(select[^;]*;)/,arr) && arr[2]==id{
  gsub(/\n/,"",arr[3])
  print arr[3]
  exit
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

One option with `awk` could be matching the start of the line with -- 6. where 6 is the ID.

Then move to the next line, and set a variable that the start of the part that you want to match is `seen`

Then print all lines that do not start with a space and are seen.

Set seen to 0 when encountering an "empty" line

Concatenate the lines that you want in the output as a single line, and at the end remove the trailing space.

```
gawk -v ID=6 '
match($0, "^-- "ID"\\.") {
  seen=1
  next
}
/^[[:space:]]*$/ {
  seen=0
}
seen {
  a = a $0 " "
}
END {
  sub(/ $/, "", a)
  print a
}
' file.sql
```

Or as a single line

```
gawk -v ID=6 'match($0,"^-- "ID"\\."){seen=1;next};/^[[:space:]]*$/{seen=0};seen{a=a$0" "};END{sub(/ $/,"",a);print a}' file.sql
```

Output

```
select distinct(native_country) from census where native_country like '%land%';
```

---

Another option with `gnu awk` setting the row separator to an "empty" line and using a regex with a capture group to match all lines after the initial `-- ID` match that do not start with a space

```
gawk -v ID=6 '
match($0, "\\n-- "ID"\\.[^\\n]*\\n(([^[:space:]][^\\n]*(\\n|$))*)", m) {
  gsub(/\n/, " ", m[1])
  print m[1]
}
' RS='^[[:space:]]*$' file
```